# Lost ability to be admin on SQL Server Reporting Services 2005

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I used to be able to go to `http://myserver/reports` and after I supplied my local account information (which was a member of "Administrators"), I would get the "Home" page of SQL Server Reporting Services along with the "Site Settings" link at the top right.

Now, when I log in, that's gone and it seems I'm just a "regular user" because the "Site Settings" menu is no longer there.  Neither is the "Properties" tab, nor the "New Data Source", "Upload File", etc...

How can I get that functionality back?  Where do I look?  In the ReportServer database?  ReportManager.config?  Web.config?

My local account is already part of local "Administrators", so I would think I should get the complete menu, but I'm not.

Is there another back-door "Administrator" account that I can log in as and then get my first Administrator account back up and running?

Answer (score 2):

My issue solved after I tick 'Apply default Setting' at Report Server Virtual Directory setting on the Reporting Services Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that someone took out the local admin group from "System Administrator" (Site Settings...Configure site-wide security).

You may be able to hack the ReportServer database:

In the ReportServer database:

- In the Users table there should "BUILTIN\Administrators"
- In the Roles table there should "System Administrator", TaskMask = 110101011
- In the PolicyUserRole table, there should be a row with the GUIDs from User and Role above. The Policy ID = EBFA3A83-8497-4A39-9B5C-62E0240D2924

Comment: ok, some of that information is there. some isn't.  Q: Under Policies table, I have 2 policies, one with PolicyFlag = 1, another PolicyFlag = 0.
What does the PolicyFlag represent?

Answer (score -2):

you need to be in the 'report server admins' security group
which is different from the 'administrators' group

Comment: Please tell me more.  Where do I look for this group?

Comment: Seem to recall it's a local group on the report server itself.

Comment: There is no local RS admin group set up by the SQL Server install. There may be a local group specific to your setup.

Comment: The $ groups are only for the *service accounts*