# SSRS 2005 Security and Data Source tabs not visible in Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to recover an old SSRS 2005 installation. The report server itself has been recovered from a backed up image and is working fine except for a missing datasource. When I log into the Report Manager (http://localhost/reports) I do not see the extra tabs as shown [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/173a9ef2-b4ec-4fab-9f39-7ce98d486824/the-shared-data-source-reference-is-no-longer-valid?forum=sqlreportingservices) (I only see General) so I cannot replace the missing datasource. What I have tried:

- I am a member of the AD group builtin/administrators, and can see Site Settings and can configure site-wide security
- I am an admin on the local machine
- I have accessed Report Manager with IE in admin mode and specified that localhost is in IE's trusted sites
- Applied default settings to the Virtual Directory as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707219/lost-ability-to-be-admin-on-sql-server-reporting-services-2005)

I believe that local administrators are always granted admin access to an SSRS installation so am pretty confused. Could this be something to do with the server having been recovered from an image? Or are there permissions I may have lost for some reason? Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I needed to disable anonymous access to the Reports websites "Reports" and "ReportServer" by going to IIS => Web Sites => Default Website => Properties => Directory Security => Authentication and access control => uncheck "Enable anonymous access".

[image]

I did a few other things in addition to the above but I think the anonymous access was the key:

- Identified the admin login via its [distinctive SID](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/07/22/how-can-i-determine-if-the-local-administrator-account-has-been-renamed-on-a-computer/)
- Logged in as this admin
- Enabled the disabled "Administrator" account (which on my machine neither had the admin roles, nor was the original admin account) and gave it admin permissions